# Need help showing $(a^p + b^p) \le (a^2 + b^2)^{p/2}$, where $p \ge 2$, and $a,b \ge 0$.

Tags: inequality

I've been so far trying to show:

$(\frac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2})^{p/2} + (\frac{b^2}{a^2 + b^2})^{p/2}  \le 1.$

Also, it holds true that $\frac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2} \le 1$ and $\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}\le 1.$

I'm struggling with how to tie all of this together to get the desired result. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give another approach. Note that by homogenity, it suffices to check the inequality is true for all $t\geq 0$:
$$ (1+t^2)^{\frac{p}{2}} -t^p -1 \geq 0.$$

Set $\phi(t)=(1+t^2)^{\frac{p}{2}} -t^p -1$. Then note $\phi(0)=0$. Then by taking derivative, we have 
\begin{align*}
 \phi^\prime (t)&=\frac{p}{2} (1+t^2)^{\frac{p}{2} -1}(2t) -p t^{p-1}\\
&=p t\left((1+t^2)^{\frac{p-2}{2}}-t^{p-2}\right).
\end{align*}
Hence $\phi^\prime (t)\geq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$.
This implies the inequality is true.

Answer (score 1):

(Rather complete) hint: Using the binomial theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem ) on the right hand side, you find that every term of the right-hand side is positive. Leaving away certain terms yields smaller values. If you leave away the mixed terms, only $a^p + b^p$ will remain there!

Answer (score 1):

Just expand
$$(a^p+b^p)^2=a^{2p}+b^{2p}+2a^pb^p$$
and if $p$ is even:
$$(a^2+b^2)^p=a^{2p}+...+\binom {p} {p/2}a^pb^p+...+b^{2p}$$
it is trivial.

If $p$ is odd:
$$(a^2+b^2)^p=a^{2p}+...+\binom {p} {(p-1)/2}a^{p-1}b^{p+1}+\binom {p} {(p+1)/2}a^{p+1}b^{p-1}+...+b^{2p}$$
$$\Rightarrow\binom {p} {(p-1)/2}a^{p-1}b^{p-1}(a^2+b^2)\ge 2\binom {p} {(p-1)/2}a^{p-1}b^{p-1}ab\ge 2a^pb^p$$

Answer (score 0):

First, let's show that
$$\forall q\ge 1,\forall 0\le x\le1,x^q+(1-x)^q\le 1$$

This is obvious since $x^q\le x$ and $(1-x)^q\le 1-x$, so we have $x^q+(1-x)^q\le x+1-x=1$.

Next, substitute $x=\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}$ and $q=\frac p2$. We get the desired inequality

$$
a^p+b^p\le (a^2+b^2)^{\frac p2}$$